# How to use UWP PointOfService API for SocketScan D700 in SPP mode

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode-scanner, socketscan, pointofservice

When I pair a SocketScan D700 via Bluetooth to a Windows 10 (1803/17134.286) desktop computer in SPP mode, then the barcode scanner is listed in "Other devices" in the settings menu "Bluetooth & other devices".

According to [Terry Warwick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9523542/terry-warwick) this [shouldn't prevent](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/1014) the Windows.Devices.PointofService.BarcodeScanner API to work with the scanner.

However, the [sample UWP app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner) is unable to claim the D700 barcode scanner once it's paired.
Also the API call below returns a null value

```
var x = await Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeScanner.GetDefaultAsync();
```

My question now, is how do I claim the D700 barcode scanner using the PointOfService API?

The SocketScan 10 desktop (binary) application from SocketScan does work and is able to 'claim' the scanner and function in keyboard wedge mode. Indicating that the scanner itself is working fine. (Of course I'm not running the socketscan software when testing the UWP sample app.)

In order to set the scanner to SPP mode I (1) first unpaired the scanner on both the PC and the scanner itself. (2) performed a factory reset of the scanner, and then (3) scanned the SPP mode barcode #FNB00F40000#, and then (4) simply paired it again with the computer. Subsequently the sample app is unable to claim the scanner.

I paired the scanner using the settings dialogs from win10:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jasper,
I am pretty sure the problem is that this 'version' of the D700 friendly name is not what Windows 10 POS is looking for, and I am guessing this scanner predates our addition of the Windows POS UUID we added to the SDP record.
So, your option is:
1) Change the friendly Name to what Windows 10 is looking for ("Socket CHS" I think but need to double check).  The only way you can do this is to setup and run our SocketScan10 Keyboard wedge software (available on our web site).  Then, using ScannerSettings, there is an option to change the friendly name.
Or 2) alternatively, I think I could generate a barcode for you to scan that will do it also.  Send me your Serial Number so we can do it 'right'.

Regards, 
Len - Socket Mobile

Comment: Hi Len, the serial number of this D700 is: 17508550001230217 (Revision E). It'd be great if it can be configured to work with win10 using a barcode.

Comment: Thanks for the assist here Len!

Comment: @Jason, so you need a Code128 barcode that has the following text:
#FNB0002Socket CHS [D2103B]#
I am not sure how to post an image, but you should be able to go to any free barcode generator site and paste in that text.
Note that for most sites you will need to convert the '#'s to the hex equivalents, %23, so:
%23FNB0002Socket CHS [D2103B]%23

This site is pretty good:

http://www.barcode-generator.org/

Comment: Thanks Len, I'll be able to test this next Friday when I'm back on location at work. I'll get back to you.

Comment: That worked! I however had to change the barcode using the socketscan 10 keyboard wedge scanner settings dialog. The scanner wouldn't accept my generated barcodes as commands instead of regular barcodes.

Comment: @jasper, Thanks for the update...glad to hear you got it working.  Yes, seems there is something wrong with the barcode info I sent you...We will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

@Jasper,

Without using the Bluetooth Pairing APIs to actually connect the device you will need to connect the paired device within Settings then you should be able to discover and pair.

I would not suggest using GetDefault as there is no guarantee which device it will find each time it is run.  Please review the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-basics-enumerating) on other discovery mechanisms to use.  I would suggest starting with the Device Picker.

Terry Warwick, Microsoft

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks for the quick response. I did in fact pair it using the windows 10 settings. I added a screenshot of the setting dialog I used to pair via Bluetooth. After pairing, the device cannot be discovered using the sample app or the GetDefaultAsync() method.

Comment: Jasper - Please install BarcodeRW from the Windows Store. Click on the gear icon in the upper right, choose POS Device Setup, select Enable for the Barcode Scanner.  See if the scanner appears in the Devices connected.  If not, we may need help from Socket Mobile.

Comment: Unfortunately this app also can't detect the scanner, I'm hoping the reaction of Len in this topic will help me out further. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update in case anyone is looking into a similar solutions:

The newer Socket Mobile devices, i.e., scanners made after mid 2018, or any S700, S740, are equipped with a feature called Auto Connect Capability (ACC mode, in which the scanner tries to connect to the host). This mode turned out to be in conflict with Microsoft POS APIs. If you are using Windows POS, make sure your scanner is set in the normal SPP mode (the SPP barcode for Android 7 or older version, if you want to find it in your scaner's user guide or on the paper insert that comes with the package) before pairing in Windows Settings.

Regards,
Long - Socket Mobile